# How to design a set of database tables with dynamic attributes?

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, cassandra, database

Now I get a problem:

For some items in the same table(category), they may have different attributes.For example there is a table called Product with two items called A and B in it.

And the attributes that A has are `id, name, attr01, attr03, attr04`

And the attributes that B has are `id, name, attr02, attr03, attr05, attr06`

There may be some more items like this.

And for each attrXX attributes, its format is like this:

```
    [attrbute_name, 
    {column_id: 01, column_name: xxx, relationship: xxx, value: xxx, unit: xxx},
    {column_id: 02, column_name: xxx, relationship: xxx, value: xxx, unit: xxx},
    {column_id: 03, column_name: xxx, relationship: xxx, value: xxx, unit: xxx},
    ...]
```

The number of columns in a attr is not fixed.

I got a little bit confused because this is totally different with the database I designed before. Thus I want to ask you guys how to design a set of tables for storing data with the format mentioned above. The database I am gonna use is MySQL. So I want a solution in MySQL environment.

Also I heard that I can solve this question by using NoSQL database like MongoDB or Cassandra. Could you tell me how to use such a NoSQL database into solving my question? I am not sure my client will accept it, but I want to introduce it to him.

Comment: I suggset you to signup to course here https://education.mongodb.com and learn about MongoDB. I warn you, there's no SQL in MongoDB, but there some other possibilities to fetch data, like aggregation framework. On the other hand, you can use EAV schema (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) in MySQL and use SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks relational to me.

You would have tables like:

```
Product (id, name)
Attribute (id, name)
ProductHasAttribute (ProductId, AttributeId)
Column (id, AttributeId, name, relationship, value, unit)
```

The contents of ProductHasAttribute would be:

```
A, 1
A, 3
A, 4
B, 2
B, 3
B, 5
B, 6
```

To get all the attributes of a product P:

```
select A.name
from ProductHasAttribute PA
inner join Attribute A on A.id = PA.AttributeID
where PA.ProductID = P
```

Column may need to be changed depending on whether the values depend only on attribute, or they also depend on the product.